# Get MongoDB database instance in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to take the already defined MongoDB database instance in Node.js. I found a couple of manuals, which explain how to query and print the result data, for example:

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const assert = require("assert");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

const findRestaurants = function (db, callback) {

    const cursor = db.collection("restaurants").find();

    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {

        assert.equal(err, null);

        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

    assert.equal(null, err);

    findRestaurants(db, function () {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

According to this example, in order to print the DB content I have to wrap the query with `MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {…});` and this will automatically initialize the `db` object.

Is there a way to expose the `db` object without additional wrappers, callbacks etc. in order to simplify the codebase and the future database manipulation, e.g. pass to functions, perform CRUD-operations?